# How to encrypt url parameter in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have to encrypt url parameter in codeigniter. So that i have to include "encrypt" library but When I load library -$this->load->library('encrypt'); it shows following error-
The Encrypt library requires the Mcrypt extension.
What I do now?
Thanks.

Comment: Windows or LInux ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486055/codeigniter-encryption-on-production-server-and-local-server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798048/php-error-the-encrypt-library-requires-the-mcrypt-extension-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install `sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt` if it is wamp enable the php configs and able to see it in the out put of `phpinfo()`

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

Restart the apache after your changes

Comment: DId you set the encryption key in the config ?

Comment: Yeah I set the encryption key in config but still I am getting that error.

Comment: can you please put a test page and print the results of phpinfo() and find the mcrypt info.

Comment: I am getting error on localhost but it is working fine on server. Thanks Bira for your help.

Comment: can you help me to decrypt url parameter on another page and how to access it.  I have done to encrypt as - $this->email->message("Click <a href='http://examon.com/index.php/exam/unsub_notification?".$this->encrypt->encode('sub_id='.$value->sub_id)."'>here</a> to unsubscribe");. I want to decrypt sub_id on another page.